# How to add Extension in Atom Editior?

Tags: atom-editor

I want to add the extension in the Atom editor like Color Picker, Bracket, Git extension, etc.

Maybe I install the extension in Visual Studio Code in a simple way:
You can browse and install extensions from within VS Code. Bring up the Extensions view by clicking on the Extensions icon in the Activity Bar on the side of VS Code or the View: Extensions command (Ctrl+Shift+X).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery

how to work the same process in Atom Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in Visual Studio Code, there are several ways to install packages in Atom.

### Command palette

Open the [command-palette](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#command-palette) and type *Settings View: Install Packages and Themes*. This will open the view to search and install packages.

### Atom Menu

The same view can be opened from the main menu. Click on *Preferences*, then on the *Install* tab.

### CLI

You can also [browse packages](https://atom.io/packages) online and install the from the CLI using `apm install <package-name>`.